# input WHERE clause throws exception when using GT in hadoop.cassandra.cql3

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, cql3

Im having difficulty restricting the range of columns my MapReduce job iterates over when using the Greater Than (>) symbol.

Im using setInputWhereClauses() to specify the column range, e.g.:

```
CqlConfigHelper.setInputWhereClauses(conf, "ts > '634926385000000000'");
```

This works as expected using LT (<) but throws an InvalidRequestException when I use GT (>).

> java.lang.RuntimeException
>           at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingRecordReader$RowIterator.executeQuery(CqlPagingRecordReader.java:646)
>   Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:Invalid restrictions found on ts)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$prepare_cql3_query_result.read(Cassandra.java:39567)

Can anyone suggest why it considers the use of GT as being an "invalid restriction"?

**UPDATE**

Ive found in the logs the query that CqlPagingRecordReader is generating:

```
CqlPagingRecordReader: partition keys: ["key"]
CqlPagingRecordReader: cluster columns: ["ts"]
CqlPagingRecordReader: row key validator:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type
CqlPagingRecordReader: previous RowKey: null, new row key: 1:
CqlPagingRecordReader: type: 2, query: SELECT * FROM "test_cf"
    WHERE token("key") = token(?)  AND "ts" > ?
    AND ts>'634926385000000000' LIMIT 3 ALLOW FILTERING
```

So it looks like my custom WHERE clause is conflicting with the record paging. Any ideas how I get around this?

Comment: I agree with your diagnosis, but I don't see a way of setting a default/starting value for your CqlPagingRecordReader... The upcoming 2.0 version of cassandra will support better pagination, maybe that will solve this problem for your? See http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-cassandra-2-0 ...

Comment: @omnibear, its possible that C* 2.0 might solve the issue (although I havent seen anything specifically pertaining to this). In the mean time, I have modified the CqlPagingRecordReader class to handle this type of behaviour and will simply deploy a custom built apache-cassandra-1.2.8.jar to my hadoop cluster.

Comment: Followup at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5892